# i have a question to select xpath in sellenium(python)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

i was trying to click some button in the page but it changes when it is available so that mine is not working.
basically, normally it's the only one section but changes into one that contains multiple buttons. and i am aiming to click buying or another buttons when it shows but i kept failing.

when it's unavailable(to click buying or shipping button), it looks like this.

```
 <div class="XqRGHcrncz">
  <ul class="_3YA58cPPsy">
   <li class="_3nAZvQO51p N=a:pcs.mylist">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" class="_3Dy-2NaoiG" aria-pressed="false">
      <span class="_3nBu7xChUl"><span class="blind">찜하기</span></span>
        <em class="_1c-2nfzJqH">13</em></a></li></ul></div>
```

but when it is available, buying button appears. everything is same but the starting from
li class, it changes a bit.
li class became

```
   <li class="_3nAZvQO51p N=a:pcs.mylist">
```

and the rest changed too.

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="OgETmrvExa">
       <span class="blind">구매하기</span>
```

---

how can i make xpath to click the element that shows only available?
the main problem is that div is changing.
xpath is sometimes

```
    //*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/fieldset/div[7]/ul[1]/li/a
```

but sometimes it is

```
    //*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/fieldset/div[8]/ul[1]/li/a
```

so that the div[] is changing. i tried css selector to click it when it turned into new page,

```
  buy=driver.find_css_selector(div.XqRGHcrncz) 
  lists = buy.find_elements_by_tag_name("ul")
  if len(lists) == 2: buy.click()
```

but when the page is loaded to available, it is not working at all...
i was trying to use xpath like this,

```
while True:

lists = buy.find_elements_by_tag_name("ul")
if len(lists) == 2:
    break 

else:
    print("구매불가")
    driver.refresh()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

and then

```
   driver.implicitly_wait(10)
   xpath='//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/fieldset/div[8]/ul[1]/li/a'
   driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

but as i mentioned, the xpath is changing and there is no use. the div[number] <- this changes so that it does not working as it is wrong xpath.
what should i do?? i would be really appreciate if anyone helps me.

(just in case, this is my page that i want to click when it became available...
https://smartstore.naver.com/hwaflora/products/5192517936 thank you)

Comment: use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[@class='_3Dy-2NaoiG'])[1]")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to find element by text, is it stable?구매하기

so the code looks like that:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='구매하기']"
```

or by preceding xpath feature:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a/preceding::span[text()='찜하기']")
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath of your element is
`String button = "//li[contains(@class,'_3nAZvQO51p N')]/a"`
Now, you mentioned that until it is available there are more elements below it, for example this:
`String loading = "//li[contains(@class,'_3nAZvQO51p N')]/a//em"`
You can wait until this element disappears. The syntax in Java is:
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);`
`wait.until((ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(loading))));`
Now you can find and click the `button` element